# Magento2 configurable product - multiple options prices

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, simple-product, superattribute

I run into a strange issue with creating configurations for a configurable product via magento2 backend.
The following scenario:
I want to create a configurable product with 3 attributes so I did

- in backend click "create new product (configurable)"
- click on "create configurations"
- select 3 attributes with all their possible values[image]
- and now I want to enter the price for their possible values in relation to each other, but the interface let me only select on attribute
  [image]

I want to input prices for the available combinations of attributes/options:

(attribute1/option1) + (attribute2/option1) + (attribute3/option1)

(attribute1/option1) + (attribute2/option1) + (attribute3/option2)

(attribute1/option1) + (attribute2/option2) + (attribute3/option1)

(attribute1/option1) + (attribute2/option2) + (attribute3/option2)

(attribute1/option2) + (attribute2/option1) + (attribute3/option1)

(attribute1/option2) + (attribute2/option1) + (attribute3/option2)

(attribute1/option2) + (attribute2/option2) + (attribute3/option1)

(attribute1/option2) + (attribute2/option2) + (attribute3/option2)

But it seems to be impossible through the provided interface...
Did anyone get a solution to input those prices?

---

Comment: I think it's not possible in this interface, but you can do it later, when the simple products have been created (if you did not already do this :P) However, more of a workaround then a solution here.

Comment: @DavidVerholen thanks, thats what i am feared of...